# Parametric Equation along a line segment

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

I am having some trouble understanding how to determine the parametric equation of a line segment between A(1,1) and B(-1,1).

I did some research and came across the following relation:

$$x(t)=(1-t)\times 1+t\times (-1)=-2t+1$$
$$y(t)=(1-t)\times1+t\times1=1$$

However they find $x(t)=-t$ and $y(t)=1$

What am I doing wrong with the x component ?

Comment: With parametric equations we need to specify our interval for $t$. In your equations, you are assuming $0 \leq t \leq 1$. In "their" answer, they have $-1 \leq t \leq 1$. Essentially, one may think about a particle moving between the points and $t$ tells us the time it takes. Their answer takes 2 seconds, your answer takes 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking that $t \in [0,1]$ while they allow $t \in [-1,1]$.  Given the proper range of $t$, you are both getting the same result.  When the allowable range of the parameter is restricted you need to specify the range.

In this case, because $y$ is constant, any parameterization of $x$ that takes it over $[-1,1]$ is correct.  If $y$ is not constant, you need to synchronize them.  For example, if we wanted the segment from  $(0,0)$ to $(3,4)$ we could say $x(t)=3t, y(t)=4t, t \in [0,1]$ or $x(t)=t, y(t)=\frac 43t, t \in [0,3]$

Comment: Could you perhaps add in your answer a step by step method on how to find this type of parametric equations so that I will be able to redo it?

Comment: @Carpediem: Since they want one endpoint to be $t=-1$ and the other $t=1$ we can say $x(t)=(\frac t2+\frac 12)\times -1 + (-\frac t2+\frac 12)\times 1=-t$.  The point is that the stuff in parentheses should be $0$ at one endpoint of the range in $t$ and $1$ at the other.  I just usually do it by inspection.